# Can I add a link on my iphone settings app like Facebook and Twitter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, settings, root.plist

I defined the Root.plist for my iPhone app, but I would like to include a link like the Twitter and Facebook apps have in the settings. Is this possible? I couldn't find any type that would allow me to do that on [Apple's dpcumentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/RootContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007018-SW1).

Comment: you want to open default twitter app from your app ? or just want to open setting page of twitter or fb

Comment: @PJR Forget the twitter and fb, those were just examples. I would like to include a link in my settings app.

Comment: so you want to open general setting from app ?

Comment: No. I want to include a link to www.foo.com in the app settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that, between, you can make your settings inside your app instead of being in the settings.app, This kit may help you: [InAppSettingsKit](http://inappsettingskit.com/)